# Why is the child QObject still accessible when the parent is deleted?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, ownership

Trying to learn more about PyQt I wrote a small script that:

- Creates an `QObject` `a`
- Creates an `QObject` `b` with `a` as its parent
- Deletes `a`

At this point I expect the object to which the name `b` is point to have been deleted as well. The documentation of Qt (not PyQt!) [says](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#details):

> The parent takes ownership of the object; i.e., it will automatically
> delete its children in its destructor.

But `b` still points to an existing object.
I also tried an explicit garbage collection without any change.
Trying to access `a` via `b`'s `parent()` method fails though, as expected.

Why is the `QObject` referenced by `b` not deleted when `a`, which "owns" `b`, is deleted?

I have added the print outputs as comments below:

```py
import gc

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject


def tracked_qobjects():
    return [id(o) for o in gc.get_objects() if isinstance(o, QObject)]


def children(qobject: QObject):
    return [id(c) for c in qobject.findChildren(QObject)]


a = QObject()
b = QObject(parent=a)
print(f"QObjects tracked by gc: {tracked_qobjects()}")
# QObjects tracked by gc: [140325587978704, 140325587978848]
print(f"Children of a: {children(a)}")
# Children of a: [140325587978848]

del a
print(f"QObjects tracked by gc: {tracked_qobjects()}")
# QObjects tracked by gc: [140325587978848]

gc.collect()  # not guaranteed to clean up but should not hurt
print(f"QObjects tracked by gc: {tracked_qobjects()}")
# QObjects tracked by gc: [140325587978848]

# Since https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#details says:
# "The parent takes ownership of the object; i.e., it will automatically delete
# its children in its destructor."
# I expect that b now points to a non-existent object.
# But no, this still works! Maybe because we are in PyQt5 and
# not a C++ application?
print(id(b))
# 140325587978848
print(b)
# <PyQt5.QtCore.QObject object at 0x7fa018d30a60>

# The parent is truly gone though and trying to access it from its child raises the "wanted" RuntimeError
print(b.parent())
# RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QObject has been deleted
```

Comment: PyQt/PySide objects are wrappers around Qt objects, so there's a Python part and a C++ part. If Qt deletes the C++ part, the Python wrapper will be left behind, so attempting to call any Qt methods may raise a runtime error.

Comment: @ekhumoro I got that alright but was confused why the calls to `id()` and the implicit call to `__repr__()` did return values. My answer should be a good answer I hope?

Comment: Dear people who closed this, it is not a *duplicate* just because there are closely *related* other questions. This Q&A provides a small, understandable example (via my own journey :o) ) and can be a nice reference for others who reach the same confusion.

Comment: Your answer is unclear on the main point, which I gave in my comment above. There are always ***two*** distinct objects to deal with. Qt knows nothing about Python, so all it can ever do is delete the C++ part. The value returned by `id()` only relates to the PyQt wrapper, because Python likewise knows nothing about the underlying C++ part. The Python parts will only be garbage-collected if there are no other references held for them. This is clearly not the case in your example, since `b` is still in `globals()` (unlike `a`, which is the only *Python* reference you explictly delete).

Comment: PS: your question has been linked as a duplicate because the topic is quite commonly encountered on SO and has been covered many times before. This should be helpful to anyone else arriving here who has similar questions but requires more details. If you want to experiment more, I would suggest you take a look at some of the functionality available in the [PyQt sip module](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/sip/sip-module.html).

Comment: @bugmenot123 Your journey is *yours* :-) We cannot provide answers for "anybody's journey", yet we should still close ambiguous questions such as yours, because you only prompted a specific test case that doesn't face a *searchable* common condition: further research would eventually show the links above, or completely unrelated posts, as your request would be shown in the middle of dozens of other posts matching a too generic search query, especially for such an ambiguous title (consider how many extremely different variations of the same question could be asked without finding your post).

Comment: @bugmenot123 Note that a closed question doesn't mean that it's off topic or completely invalid. We probably need some canonical post about this, having proper question title, body and tags, but getting something like that is extremely difficult, if not even impossible. SO guidelines suggest that we should generally close "meta" questions like these, which may not be a good solution for the specific post, but still better than having dozens (hundreds? thousands?) of questions that all revolve around the same answer. Imagine having hundreds of such broad question for any topic and any language.

Answer (score 0):

This was a red herring. Python can still provide the memory address (id) that the name `b` is point to and the type of the object expected to be there, but the actual object *has* been destroyed:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject


def children(qobject: QObject):
    return [id(c) for c in qobject.findChildren(QObject)]


def on_destroyed():
    print("x_x")


a = QObject()
b = QObject(parent=a)
b.destroyed.connect(on_destroyed)
print(f"Children of a: {children(a)}")

print("Deleting a...")
del a
print("a has been deleted.")

# Since https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#details says:
# "The parent takes ownership of the object; i.e., it will automatically delete its children in its destructor."
# b now points to a non-existent object.

# Python still knows its memory address and type:
print(id(b))
print(b)

# But trying to do anything with it will fail with the RuntimeError:
print(b.objectName())
```

results in

```
Children of a: [140051377982048]
Deleting a...
x_x
a has been deleted.
140051377982048
<PyQt5.QtCore.QObject object at 0x7f6040a28a60>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../parental_issues.py", line 30, in <module>
    print(b.objectName())  # RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QObject has been deleted
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QObject has been deleted
```

The error message is about `b`. Its (wrapped) C++ object has been deleted so the Python object is errorneous.